# AngularJS $scope Error with Popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want a popup when the user clicks on a text-box. I have it working when doing a simple statement like the following:

```
$scope.FriendsList = function(){
            alert("Hi Friends!");
        },
```

But when doing it like the following, I get an error:

```
$scope.FriendsList = new Friend({
    $scope.FriendsList = function(){
        alert("Hi Friends!");
    },
});
```

The issue is with the `$scope.FriendsList = function(){...` In Visual Studio it says that it `"Expects :"` instead of the `"."` Any ideas on how to get this running?

Thanks!!

Comment: What does the constructor function of Friend require as a parameter? A function?

Comment: I am not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is giving Friend an invalid JSON.

```
$scope.FriendsList = new Friend({
    $scope.FriendsList = function(){
        alert("Hi Friends!");
    },
});
```

is just like

```
$scope.FriendsList = new Friend({invalid});
```

Maybe you are trying to pass in a function

```
$scope.FriendsList = new Friend(function () {
        alert("Hi Friends!");
});
```

or

```
$scope.FriendsList = new Friend({
    FriendsList : function(){
        alert("Hi Friends!");
    }
});
```

Maybe you just want to make a new Friend obj then display a pop up, in which case

```
$scope.FriendsList = function() {
    new Friend();
    alert("Hi Friends!");
});
```

Comment: This doesn't give me an error in Visual Studio, but when running the code and clicking on the text-box, it only gives me a Stack error. Any suggestions? It doesn't have a popup that says "Hi Friends!"

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do here. What is Friend? Why is it needed? I don't get why you can't just leaving FriendsList as a simple function

Comment: This code is an example from a bigger project that I am working on... I really need to keep _$scope.FriendsList = new Friend_. Inside is where I do operations.

Comment: Maybe just pass Friend a function that alerts? I updated the answer